# Laravel Schema Builder alter storage engine

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, schema, storage-engines

I am trying to alter a table and change it's storage engine to `InnoDb`. When I run `php artisan migrate` it completes without error. However when I check the storage engine in Sequel Pro, nothing is changed.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tests', function(Blueprint $t) {
        $t->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $t->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('test_groups')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can only define it when you create the table, not change it afterwards.

Comment: Pretty sure @lukasgeiter is correct there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since @alexrussell confirmed my believe, I'm almost certain you can only define the storage engine when you create the table with `Schema::create()`.
However you can always use raw SQL as a last resort:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tests ENGINE = InnoDB');
```