# How to make column unique and index it in Laravel Migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to `alter` my one of my `column` on my table - and make them a `unique index`.

I tried :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('inventories', function($table)
    {           
        $table->string('sku',255)->unique();
    });
}
```

I get :

[image]

What is the most efficient way to do that ?

Comment: I think we can use a validation here to prevent this from happening. 



`eg: 'title' => 'required|unique: inventories|max:255',`

Answer (score 47):

You can add indexes separately from their definition. As [documented here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes)

```
Schema::table('inventories', function($table)
{
    $table->unique('sku');
});
```

Comment: What if I want to the change something else ? Let's say table engine, can I just do this ? `$table->engine('MYISAM');`

Comment: The engine is kind of the exception. The schema builder only allows you to define it when creating. You'll have to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501156/1903366) to alter the engine.

Comment: Here is how you can reverse this: `$table->dropUnique('inventories_sku_unique');`

Comment: what if want to chane the type?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I did this :

```
public function up()
{           
    DB::update('alter table `inventories` modify `sku` VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL');
}
```

and now It works  :

[image]

Comment: Does this apply to any dbms?

Comment: You ended up using straight MySQL instead of the Eloquent functions. That is NOT best practice when using a framework. One of the benefits of using Eloquent is that code is language agnostic, meaning it'll work with many database systems. The other answer provided is much better as it actually uses eloquent.